# Pass data structure as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three data structures,

```
Tuple<string, string> parentid = null;
var subids = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
Tuple<string, string> dname = null;

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add(parentid);
al.add(subids);
al.add(dname);
```

and I call a function which returns an `ArrayList` containing those 3 data structures.

For example

```
ArrayList al = category.getTree();
```

and now I want to pass the data structure to another method

```
string option = category.printOption(al[0], al[1], al[2], 0);
```

The `printOption` code:

```
public string printOption(Tuple<string, string> parents, List<Tuple<int, int>> subids, Tuple<string, string> dname, int indent)
```

But there is an error :

> *the best overloading method.......*

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What is the full error message and where does it occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` stores objects, so to use the contents you will need to cast each object you want to use to its correct type:

```
string option = category.printOption((Tuple<string, string>)al[0],
    (List<Tuple<int, int>>)al[1], (Tuple<string, string>)al[2], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string option = category.printOption((add your cast here) al[0], ( List< Tuple < int, int>>) al[1], (and here) al[2], 0);
```